# Showing that an operator is a Markov generator

Tags: functional-analysis, markov-process

Let $E = [0,1]$. I want to show that the operator $Af = \frac{1}{2}f''$ defined on
$$D(A) = \{f \in C(E) : f'' \in C(E), f'(0) = 0 = f'(1)\} \subset C(E)$$
is a Markov generator. This Markov generator corresponds to Brownian motion with reflecting barriers.

The definition of a Markov generator I am working with is the following.

A Markov generator is a closed Markov pregenerator $A$ for which $R(\operatorname{Id}-\lambda A) = C(E)$ for all $\lambda \geq 0$.

Now, I have shown that $A$ is a closed Markov pregenerator, so I need to show that $R(\operatorname{Id}-\lambda A) = C(E)$ for all $\lambda \geq 0$. So I fix $\lambda \geq 0$ and $g \in C(E)$, and I want to show that there is an $f \in D(A)$ such that $f - \lambda Af = g$.

This is where I am stuck. I can't, for example, use a power series $f = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda^n A^n g$ since $A$ is not everywhere defined and not bounded.

Something that might make this problem easier, which I have not proven myself so I am shying away from using it, is the following fact: For a closed Markov pregenerator $A$, if $R(\operatorname{Id}-\lambda A) = C(E)$ for small enough $\lambda > 0$, then the same is true for all $\lambda \geq 0$.

Comment: Maybe proceed by contradiction. Assume a $g$ exists such that it is not in the range. Then you can use a little bit of inner product magic to perhaps get to where you want to go.

Comment: Another option could be to recover the polynomials (by recovering the individual monomials and using linearity) and then showing $A$ is closed. (I think this works.)

Comment: The function $f$ can be explicitly computed: $f(x)=\sum_n (1+\lambda n^2/2)^{-1}\cos(n\pi x)\int g(y) \cos(n\pi y)\,dy$. Of course you need to check that this sum converges and $f$ satisfies $f-\lambda Af=g$.